MatrixRankWarning is printing to stdout despite being caught
I'm catching the following:
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve, MatrixRankWarning

try:
    out = spsolve(AMatrixT, dist)
    out /= out.sum()
    if not np.isnan(out).any():
        return out
except MatrixRankWarning:
    continue

As I understand it, this should just quietly ignore the warning. Yet, I'm seeing
my_file.py:54: MatrixRankWarning: Matrix is exactly singular
  out = spsolve(AMatrixT, dist)

which corresponds to exactly the line in which I'm applying spsolve. Why is the warning still displayed? And how could I ignore it?

It's a warning, not an exception (and most likely it's on stderr, not stdout).
